# Post binary data to flask and save it to xlsx produces corrupted file

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, csv, binary, xlsx

I do have two communicating backends that request then analyse/transform data :

- The first is a NodeJS, that requests CSV and excel files from another application, then forwards the response body (which is the binary data of the files) to the python backend to analyse them.
- The python backend is a flask app, my problem is when i save the binary data received in the python API, the files are corrupted and unreadable. I tried to utf-8 encode and 'wb' the files, still the same thing.

Please note that if i write the file with node, it's readable and fine, and the `console.log()` and `print` both display the same body data, it's just the writnig to the file that doesn't seem to go well for me.

Here is the necessary parts of my code :

**Nodejs :**

```
r.get({url : link, encoding: 'binary'}, function (error, res, body) {
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        console.log("requesting data transformation");
        request.post({url : "http://127.0.0.1:5000/app_name/api/v1.0/transform", body : body} , function (error, res, json_body) {
            console.log("requesting");
            console.log(json_body)
        });
    }
})
```

**Python :**

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/app_name/api/v1.0/transform', methods=['POST'])
def transform():
    print request.get_data()

    with open('binaryxl.xlsx', 'wb') as output_file:
        output_file.write(request.get_data())
        output_file.close()

    return "ok"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

**UPDATE**

If i write the file using fs (binary mode), then read it, and post the data i read, and added content-type according to the docs, everything goes fine and the excel is readable, but i dont want to open/save/close, i want to be the most efficient possible in my code...

New node code :

```
fs.readFile('path/to/file.xlsx', function
    read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw
        err;
    }
    console.log(data);
    request.post({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/app_name/api/v1.0/transform",
            body: data,
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            }
        },
        function (error, res, json_body) {
            console.log("requesting");
            console.log(json_body)
        });
});
```

Any ideas ?